# Wrong decision?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Playing at 6 hand table. I'm in the UTG+2 position.

UTG+1 raises to 4BB (4800 chips) on the flop (A♥ K♥ 5♥).

I have 9♥7♥ (a flopped flush), so I called.

I lost to Full house on River.

My question is: Should I have gone all in on the flop?

Comment: Well what was the action on the turn, action on the river, stack sizes, is it a tournament or cash game? Give us the full situation.

Comment: I agree with @Grinch91. There are a lot of important variables you left out.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever lose against a `full-house` on this particular flop, this is a cooler. It's actually the best case when you have *flush* against a *set* on the flop (the case).

There's another problem here. Your flush *is not strong*. You don't fear if your opponent has a stronger flush, you fear a `4th flush card`, which will convert your hand into a semi-trash.

You want to be really aggressive on the flop and `don't just call`, re-raise and get him all-in if you're putting above 30% of your stack here by raising. If he has a `set` and the board pairs, *it's a cooler* and you can't do anything about it, it just happens.

I said above *the best case when villain has a set* because this is the case that villain will cheerfully give away all his money on this scary flop. In fact, there is a ton of hands he would cheerfully gave in on this flop:

- Sets (because they can't allow you a `4th card to flush`, they think the same as you.
- Many 2-pairs (`AK, A5`), which also can't allow for `4th flush card`
- Many 1-card flushes (`Q,J,T` of ♥), because some players just don't pay attention to pot odds and will chase no matter what.

The best `treatment` for all above cases is to charge them around `2/3 to 3/4` on flop and around `1/2` on the turn. You want to extract money from them if they're a bit `tightish` and at the same time you want to give them wrong odds to call with worst hands or their draws (this is where you make money).

You need to act aggressive here, on the flop or at worst, the turn. If a `4th flush card` comes, the action will probably freeze since you may be afraid of a higher flush and Villain may be afraid you just have any 1-heart (while he has nothing or a 2♥) and if he has a Q♥ you still did the wrong thing, waiting. Being normally aggressive early is the best move in these flops, even if you have flopped the flush.

If they're more aggro, just continue the aggression. This is one of the risks you take with hands like 9♥7♥ -- if you hesitate even when you flop a flush, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If this is a tournament the hand may play out differently than in a cash game. Stack sizes can dictate proper play as well.

If the player is a tight player his/her early position raise would typically indicate strength. If a loose player the range can't be narrowed down by position alone (not based on one bet anyway).

On the flop your play should be partially decided by your opinion on how your opponent plays and both your stack sizes. If your stack is small at this point you'll be all in no matter what. Since you have position you need to get it in there and either take it down uncontested or get a call while your most likely ahead.

If stacks are large it depends on the action before and the type of player the villain is. If it's a tight player leading out you have to decide if they lead out with an AK type of hand or a higher flush. A loose player could lead with a wider range of hands. I'd probably end up raising almost no matter what, but the tight player you can make an argument for calling and seeing how they react on the turn (since you have position).

It's difficult to give concrete advice on whether or not you should just push on the flop. The reality is that "it depends". It's going to come down to hand reading as you want to bet the minimum if you're behind and get the maximum if you're ahead. There's no one universal right play with this hand on this flop, but there are good lines based on the opponents tendencies.